# Firebase function - push notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi this is my first time working with Firebase push notifications and I'm trying to send a test push notification to a specific device and I'm getting an error when checking the functions. Here is my code and the errors, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.testPushNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

res.send("Trying to send a message")
console.log("LOGGER --- trying to send a push notification..");

const uid = 'O5cN65bAe3Mf7uMr7DCF8GlvsHA3'
const fcmToken = 'cUQ-IcReLTQ:APA91bGgDRIQfFi7k4AIo45b4sXr.........'

return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

  const user = snapshot.val();

  console.log("Username is " + user.userName);

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Push Notification',
      body: 'Test Notification message'
    }
  }

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload)
    .then(function(response) => {        // 27:30  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
    .catch(function(error) => {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
  });
})
```

If I remove the => I get the following warnings and error:

```
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload)
    .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
```

27:11  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback

27:11  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

30:12  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback

Comment: You have a bunch of eslint warnings.  I suggest doing a web search for each of those messages to find out what they mean.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 warnings and 1 error, I did some research online and followed Firebase documentation and I'm stuck with those issues. That is why I posted this just in case anyone have an idea of what I'm missing. Thank you.